# Kotlin: explicitly unnamed function arguments

Tags: kotlin, arguments, named

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Fn2<A, B, R> : BiFunction<A, B, R>, (A, B) -> R {
    @JvmDefault
    override operator fun invoke(p1: A, p2: B): R {
        ...
```

When I implement this interface:

```
object: Fn2<Int,Int,Int> {
    override fun invokeEx(accum: Int, i: Int): Int =
    accum + i
}
```

I get a warning:

> Warning:(598, 76) Kotlin: The corresponding parameter in the supertype
>   'Fn2' is named 'a'. This may cause problems when calling this function
>   with named arguments.

Is there some kind of annotation or keyword or secret name (like `it` or `_`) that I can use on the `invoke()` function definition to get rid of these warnings.  I admit I'm doing something kind of non-standard with Java/Kotlin interop that might go away when I finish refactoring, but I'm still curious.

I know there's a `@Suppress("PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")` ([thank you evilbloodydemon](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/annoying-warning-on-parameters-when-overriding-methods/682)) but I'm looking for a way to suppress it at the function signature that I'm overriding, not at the implementation.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9872

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.2.40, there is no possibility to mark a function argument as explicitly unnamed, and I'm not aware of any plans to add such a possibility.